# Django Query (aggregates and counts)

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, django-piston

Hey guys, I've got a model that looks like this:

```
class Interaction(DateAwareModel, UserAwareModel):
  page = models.ForeignKey(Page)
  container = models.ForeignKey(Container, blank=True, null=True)
  content = models.ForeignKey(Content)
  interaction_node = models.ForeignKey(InteractionNode)
  kind = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=INTERACTION_TYPES)
```

I want to be able to do one query to get the count of the interactions grouped by container then by kind. The idea being that the output JSON data structure (serialization taken care of by piston) would look like this:

```
"data": {
   "container 1": {
       "tag_count": 3, 
       "com_count": 1
   },
   "container 2": {
       "tag_count": 7, 
       "com_count": 12
   },
   ...
}
```

The SQL would look like this:

```
SELECT container_id, kind, count(*) FROM rb_interaction GROUP BY container_id, kind;
```

Any ideas on how to group by multiple fields using the ORM? (I don't want to write raw queries for this project if I can avoid id) This seems like a simple and common query.

Before you ask: I have seen the django aggregates documentation and the raw queries documentation.

**Update**
As per advice below I've created a custom manager to handle this:

```
class ContainerManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super(ContainerManager, self).get_query_set(*args, **kwargs)
        qs.filter(Q(interaction__kind='tag') | Q(interaction__kind='com')).distinct()
        annotations = {
            'tag_count':models.Count('interaction__kind'),
            'com_count':models.Count('interaction__kind')
        }
        return qs.annotate(**annotations)
```

This only counts the interactions that are of kind tag or com instead of retrieving the counts of tags and of the coms via group by. It is obvious that it works that way from the code but wondering how to fix it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom manager:

```
class ContainerManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super(ContainerManager, self).get_query_set(*args, **kwargs)
        annotations = {'tag_count':models.Count('tag'), 'com_count':models.Count('com')}
        return qs.annotate(**annotations)

class Container(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = ContainerManager()
```

Then, `Container` queries will always include `tag_count` and `com_count` attributes. You'll probably need to modify the annotations, since I don't have a copy of your model to refer to; I just guessed on the field names.

**UPDATE:**

So after gaining a better understanding of your models, annotations won't work for what you're looking for. Really the only to get counts for how many `Container`s have `kind`s of 'tag' or 'com' is:

```
tag_count = Container.objects.filter(kind='tag').count()
com_count = Container.objects.filter(kind='com').count()
```

Annotations won't give you that information. I think it's possible to write your own aggregates and annotations, so that might be a possible solution. However, I've never done that myself, so I can't really give you any guidance there. You're probably stuck with using straight SQL.

Comment: Excellent response but my main concern is this: Instead of iterating over the containers I wanted to be able to do the aggregation work within the database. I may be wrong but it seems as though this would count tags and comments for each container (loop implied) whereas using a group by clause would make better use of the DB engine. Thoughts?

Comment: There's no iteration. `annotate` works like `filter` and the rest of the queryset API. It simply tacks on stuff to the eventual SQL that will be sent to the DB. There's only one query.

Comment: Kind is actually on my interaction model, would you mind mentioning how you would do this if I wanted to annotate count where 'interaction__kind' = 'tag' or 'com'?

Comment: just insert `.filter(Q(interaction__kind='tag') | Q(interaction__kind='com')).distinct()` before `.annotate`. `Q` is in `django.db.models`.

Comment: Yeah, based on your update, it wouldn't work. I wrote the answer based on the assumption that `tag` and `com` were something "countable", i.e. foreign keys. I'll update my answer above, but you probably won't like it ;).

Comment: Thanks Chris, that is what i figured. Really appreciate the help man!